# How to create custom TextOutputFormatter for IAsyncEnumerable in a way that supports streaming?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I want to stream some customly formatted text from my WebAPI endpoint. Text should appear gradually, as soon as it's been yield.

I've made this endpoint:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> StreamAnswer(string message)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        yield return "test" + i;
    }
}
```

It returns this value:

> ["test0","test1","test2"]

Each part of this array appear one by one, every three seconds as expected.

The value is JSON-formatted array. What I want to accomplish is to make this endpoint return data so it will look like:

> test0test1test2

So I've modified my endpoint to this (notice `Produces` attribute):

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("text/plain")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> StreamAnswer(string message)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        yield return "test" + i;
    }
}
```

and created this text formatter:

```
public class PlainTextOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    public PlainTextOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
        
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type? type)
        => typeof(IAsyncEnumerable<string>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    
    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        var asyncEnumerable = context.Object as IAsyncEnumerable<string>;
        if (asyncEnumerable != null)
        {
            await using var writer = context.WriterFactory(response.Body, selectedEncoding);
            await foreach (var value in asyncEnumerable)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    await writer.WriteAsync(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and declared it in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new PlainTextOutputFormatter());
});
```

Result seems to be fine, except the text does not appear gradually. It's not streamed. Instead, the endpoint now loads nine seconds and then returns all data at once. Can you see what's blocking streaming here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `await writer.FlushAsync()` after each write:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new PlainTextOutputFormatter());
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> StreamAnswer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            yield return "test" + i;
        }
    }
}

public class PlainTextOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    public PlainTextOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));

        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type? type)
        => typeof(IAsyncEnumerable<string>).IsAssignableFrom(type);

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        var asyncEnumerable = context.Object as IAsyncEnumerable<string>;
        if (asyncEnumerable != null)
        {
            await using var writer = context.WriterFactory(response.Body, selectedEncoding);
            await foreach (var value in asyncEnumerable)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    await writer.WriteAsync(value);
                    await writer.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can test it with: `curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:5151/WeatherForecast' -H 'accept: text/plain'`

Comment: Hello. Thank you for taking the time to write this answer, but it still does not work. I've literally copy-pasted your code example into my project. Endpoint still waits 9 seconds and then responds with all "test" messages at once

Comment: @Piotrek I edited my post with my entire code and how I'm testing it

Comment: that's weird. I've just created new .net 7.0 webapp, pasted your code into `Program.cs`, launched it using `dotnet run` and used `curl` as you've shown. Still doesn't work, a few "test" messages appear, but all at once.

Comment: That is very weird